# Getting null value in db when using @embbeded in Spring boot Rest api? new to java help me out guys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Getting null values in database for the embedded Address entity. Using MySql database. The user entity is storing values fine but embedded Address entity is returning null value, can't figure out why it's not working. help me out guys.I am a beginner tried searching everywhere but no luck. Just a novice Api but it won't work the way i want it's really annoying.

**Model class**

```
 package com.example.demo;



import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
@Id
private int id; 
private String name;
@Embedded
private Address address;

public User() {

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String toString() {
    return "user [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ",Address="+address+" ]";
}
public User(int id, String name, Address address) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Model class**
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;


@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String cityname;

    private String streetname;

    private String Housename;

    public Address() {

}
public Address(String cityname, String streetname, String housename) {
        super();
        this.cityname = cityname;
        this.streetname = streetname;
        Housename = housename;
    }


public String getStreetname() {
    return streetname;
}
public void setStreetname(String streetname) {
    this.streetname = streetname;
}
public String getHousename() {
    return Housename;
}
public void setHousename(String housename) {
    Housename = housename;
}
public String getCityname() {
    return cityname;
}
public void setCityname(String cityname) {
    this.cityname = cityname;
}
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**controller class**

package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class Croller {

@Autowired
TestRepo repo;

@PostMapping("/add")
public String save(@RequestBody User mode) {
repo.save(mode);
return "details saved";
}

@GetMapping("/get")
public List<User> retrive(){
return repo.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/search")
public List<User> searchname(@RequestParam("name")String name){
    return  repo.name(name);    
}
@GetMapping("/byid/{id}")
public Optional <User> getone (@PathVariable int id){

    return repo.findById(id);
}

@PutMapping("/update")
public String updateid(@RequestBody User mode ) {
 repo.save(mode);
return " user updated sucessfully";
}

@DeleteMapping("/remove/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable int id) {
repo.deleteById(id);
return "deleted with the given id:"+ id;
}
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Repository 

package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository <User, Integer> {
 List <User> name(String name);



}


**Application.java**

package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demoapi2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demoapi2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the request you are making to the server ?

Comment: POST request {
"id":19,
"name":"Alex",
"cityname":"california",
"streetname":"ring road",
"Housename": "zelners"
}

Comment: Are you mapping above json to your entity User? Curious to know how you are creating the User entity before saving to the db.

Comment: @Alexvolowitz , the request you send should match the RequestBody class of the controller (in this case "User" class ). Posted a sample request. Can you try.

Comment: thanks buddy it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your request has to match the  `@RequestBody` object for spring to map the keys appropriately

Try this request -

```
{
   "id":19,
   "name":"Alex",
   "address":{
      "cityname":"california",
      "streetname":"ring road",
      "Housename":"Housename"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you give input as per your Model.
[image]